# swift how to pass parameter of type UIViewController<XXXDelegate>

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function to present signin/signup modal view controller. The parameter passed has to be `UIViewController<AuthViewControllerDelegate>` (`UIViewController` for presenting method, `AuthViewControllerDelegate` for delegate method)

```
static func checkAuthError(controller: UIViewController<AuthViewControllerDelegate>, err: NSError) {
    if err.code == 401 {
        let authViewController = viewControllerWithIdentifier("AuthViewController") as! AuthViewController
        authViewController.delegate = controller
        controller.presentViewController(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But I can't pass the objective c style type. Do I have to pass the same controller twice, with different types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could choose either the class or protocol type for the method argument and conditionally cast it to the other:

```
func checkAuthError(controller: UIViewController, err: NSError) {
    ...
    if authDelegate = controller as? AuthViewControllerDelegate {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a generic type constraint:

```
func checkAuthError<T: UIViewController where T: AuthViewControllerDelegate>(controller: T, err: NSError) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like

```
func checkAuthError<T: UIViewController where T: AuthViewControllerDelegate>(controller: T, err: NSError) {
    ...
}
```

will be deprecated soon, replaced by:

```
func checkAuthError<T: UIViewController>(controller: T, err: NSError)  where T: AuthViewControllerDelegate {
    ...
}
```

For clarity, the `where` clause comes after any return values.